# Eclipse can't build automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

I cloned a project from github and tried to build it. And I configured its lib but eclipse can't build it automatically, which means the bin folder is always empty. I checked the source configuration the default output is the project's bin. And I also checked run configuration, it points to my main class. And I deleted my .metadata and re-import my project. It still couldn't work. I have no idea what should I do now. This is my .classpath and .project. Can some body help me?

.classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/scala"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/scala"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="scripts"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="org/nicta/uima/ae/featExtractor/" kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java/org/nicta/uima/ae/featExtractor"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="culib/akka-actor_2.10-2.3.6.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="culib/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp-model-tagger-en-bidirectional-distsim-20140104.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="culib/de.tudarmstadt.ukp.dkpro.core.stanfordnlp-upstream-tagger-en-bidirectional-distsim-20140104.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="culib/jline-2.12.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/BIDMach.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/BIDMat.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jcublas-0.6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jcuda-0.6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jcufft-0.6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jcurand-0.6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jcusparse-0.6.5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jhdf5.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/ptplot.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

.project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
    <name>DL-IE</name>
    <comment></comment>
    <projects>
    </projects>
    <buildSpec>
        <buildCommand>
            <name>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalabuilder</name>
            <arguments>
            </arguments>
        </buildCommand>
    </buildSpec>
    <natures>
        <nature>org.scala-ide.sdt.core.scalanature</nature>
        <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
    </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need **javabuilder** as well.

Add the below to your .project file:

```
<buildCommand>
    <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
    <arguments>
    </arguments>
</buildCommand>
```

Comment: @deathlee - Glad it helped you.  If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark (found just below the voting buttons). This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.